# Add pointLight in react three fiber

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I want to add pointlight in react three fiber and it seems that it follows different syntax from usual three.js syntax.

Answer (score 1):

All three.js objects will be treated as *native JSX elements*. The general rule is that React Three Fiber components are available under the *camel-case* version. Hence do this to add a point source light like this -

```js
<pointLight position={[0, 10, -5]} intensity={1} color="#fff" />
```